# Swift for var list.enumerated()

Tags: swift, for-loop, var, let

I have an array of objects whose type is a struct with mutating functions. So I got this code:

```
for (index, object) in objects.enumerated() {
     otherArray[index] = object.someMutatingFunction(...)
}
```

This leads me to this error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'Blabla'` which I can fix by adding var:

```
for var (index, object) in objects.enumerated() {
     otherArray[index] = object.someMutatingFunction(...)
}
```

But then I get another warning `Variable 'index' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant` which I don't know how to fix elegantly. The only idea is too add a new var variable. Is there anything else I can do to prevent this warning?

Comment: Note that `enumerated()` is a method, not a property.

Comment: You are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix the `object` variable with the `var` keyword:

```
struct S {
    mutating func f() { }
}

let array = [S(), S()]

for (index, var object) in array.enumerated() {
    object.f()
}
```

Note as Hamish points out in the comment to this answer that the elements of the `array` will not be modified.  Only the local copy of `object` inside the scope of the `for` loop can be modified.

If you want to modify `array` you have to declare it `var` outside the scope of the `for` loop, then assign to `array` indices.

Comment: Actually realised that OP is looking to assign the mutated elements into another array, `otherArray` rather than the original array, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: I think you're still very correct to point it out though as the `mutating` aspect could very easily be misconstrued as doing something that modifies elements of `array`.